# How to wrap <a> elements inside of a table?

Tags: html, css

At first, yes I did search and found a lot of similar question and no, non of the solutions worked for me.

Now here is my main problem:

I try to get `"a"` elements in line and wrap if there are to much to fit inside the parent `"td"`.
But I can either get them in line or warp.

`"1st"` and "`2nd_main_container"` are in line. the `"1st"` has a fixed width `"2nd"` take the remaining space of `"wrapper"`.

I already tried with float inlineblock adding `"width:100%"` and my last try (see code) every `"a"` in a seperate "`div"` inside another main `"div"` Floating left. They won't wrap, they just grow the main `"div"`, `"td"`, `"tr"`, `"table"` and `"2nd_main_container"`. `"wrapper"` size dose not change.

I guess my problem is that `"2nd_main_container"` has no fixed width, but thats not an option.

I hope someone can help me with a solution to this. Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/p7nhjr08/4/

here my code:

```
<style>
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #1st_main_container {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 16px;
        padding-right: 8px;
        padding-top: 8px;
        padding-bottom: 16px;
        width: 400px;
    }
    #2nd_main_container {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 16px;
        padding-top: 8px;
        padding-bottom: 16px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    #2nd_main_container th {
        font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: right;
    }
    #2nd_main_container td {
        font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    #content {
        white-space: normal;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #content div {
        float:left;
    }
    #container a {
        padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 8px;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
</style>



<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="1st_main_container">
        Something
    </div>
    <div id="2nd_main_container">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Something:
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        Something
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Something:
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        Something
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Something:
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        Something
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Something:
                    </th>
                    <td >
                        Something
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Something:
                    </th>
                    <td id="container">
                        <div id="content">
                            <div>
                                <a></a>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a></a>
                            </div>
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make a demonstration http://jsfiddle.net and post the link in your question.

Comment: Give us your thought of what would it be look like.

Comment: Your codes are so messy.

Comment: just as it ist now, only the asdf... links should be in 2,3,4 or how many lines it takes to fit all in. I also cleaned up the code a little http://jsfiddle.net/p7nhjr08/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a wrapper with variable width, containing two div-columns. first one with fixed width, and second div shall use the remaining width, correct ?

Maybe you should have a look onto **[css3 flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

Comment: ahh, I didn't know about that. This makes my life a lot easier even if it shouldn't fix the current problem. I will apply this and see if it fixes this Problem. Thx for that info regardless of the result.

Comment: depending on your needs, be aware of the browser-support of css3 features: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: Just changed to flex and everything worked fine ;) thx again.
hmm, except for opera mini all current browser support it, so all fine for me ;).